# How to use JWT in case of UI application is using SSO

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have Web APIs built in .NET 6 and has JWT authentication in place for security. As far as I know, UI client application uses to send userName/password as first request to API and then API will validate the credentials and send response back to client with JWT token, from there client application uses that token for any subsequent requests. In my case, client will not be sending explicit userName/password as it's UI is being launched by  SSO. So in this case my API will not receive user validation request and no JWT will be generated. I am confused now, how and when will I generate token for client to use other API endpoints for fetching data from my API. Any idea/suggestions please.
Or shall I change the authentication process to any other which is suitable to my scenario. Thanks

Comment: actually SSO provides you data under the hood :)

Comment: @jmvcollaborator can you please explain in detail please or provide any article on it. Thanks

Comment: which identity provider are you (or have in mind) to use ?

Comment: If you need to generate JWT's, why not have the client explicitly call an endpoint for this (regardless if and how they were logged in)?

Comment: @bavaza I did not get the question. Can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: @niler you are free to create an endpoint which generates tokens, regardless of the login process. A JWT token is simply an encoded claim string + a digital signature which authenticates the issuing server. If you need tokens for other APIs. you can ask the client to explicitly call it with user/pass, and create a token

Comment: @jmvcollaborator my client app is using DataPower to generate JWT token at their end.

Comment: @bavaza That is the point. Client will not explicitly call API to validate user with user name/password. They are reluctant to do so as they have SSO and need not to enter user name /password each time while logging in to their application.

Comment: If you client is already authenticated, you can simply issue tokens - no need to ask for user/pass. Namely, create an endpoint https://my-domain/create-token. Make sure it requires authentication. The client can POST there, and the backend should issue the token. If you need the username to be embedded in the JWT claim, get it from the SSO authentication data.

Comment: So you could check the client `jwt` and retrieve the `token claims` as your client is using `SSO` hence it should have token already, once you can check that `token credential` you are done. Because you can check the validity from given token claims. However, if you still have any blockings would better to share your `code snippet` what you are up to now.